# While upgrading to ubuntu 13.10 my battery went off, now the screen is off

Tags: installation, upgrade

while I was upgrading the new Ubuntu 13.10, my battery went off, so my laptop only shows a black screen (nothing appears on it).  Please some clues on how to recover previous data and so.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you will definitely need a live cd/usb or some other external boot media. Maybe you could try to boot a live cd and browse your files, then copy to an external backup disk before reinstalling the system... if they were in a different partition than your system, this should probably work.

If, on the other hand, you had all in the same partition, AND there was damage to the partition (unlikely, I believe, as it was just an upgrade, which doesn't repartition your disk), maybe you should use something more specialized... I used [Hiren's boot CD](http://www.hirensbootcd.org/) a long time ago, and it worked for me... it's a boot cd with a lot of useful tools for recovering. Anyway, you could still use a live ubuntu, but you would need to download specialized tools, and I don't know any.

You could also try recovering the system using the live cd, but I don't know how this works... I wouldn't do this without backing up files first.